# How to create Javascript Runtime like nodejs

Tags: javascript, runtime, v8

How can i create my own javascript runtime and what are the steps to create one?
I can't find any tutorial on the internet

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not that hard to integrate existing JavaScript engine. Most of the folks integrate [V8](https://v8.dev/) from Google (including Node.js).

A [detailed guide](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) is available at the official page.

With that being said, I strongly recommend to use Node.js directly. It supports [C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), should the existing [API](https://nodejs.org/api/) lack any features.